# Как открыть по действию две ссылки в новом окне в Chrome, OPera, IE

Tags: google-chrome, opera, javascript, internet-explorer

Добрый день. Проблема такая. Нужно открыть при нажатии на кнопку две вкладки в новом окне. Прописываю код
    window.open("http://ya.ru", '_blank');
    window.open("http://vk.com", '_blank');
в Firefox и Safari открывает две вкладки, как и нужно. В Chrome, Opera и IE открывает только одну. Каким образом можно обойти запрет на открытие второй вкладки по одному действию в этих браузерах?

Comment: Какую цель Вы преследуете? Напрямую обход невозможен.
Вы хотите показать несколько страниц (а-ля рекламная страница и собственно, запрашиваемый контент) или открытие страниц Вам нужно для выполнения системных операций (отправка данных, установка кукисов и т.д.)?

Comment: Мне нужно открыть две страницы с генерируемым адресом. С рекламой это не связано. Нужно чтобы была одна кнопка, при нажатии на неё в отдельных вкладках открываются другие сайты на нужной странице.

Comment: Думаю, это сделать нереально. Возникло 2 идеи:
1) http://jsfiddle.net/7FG5K/
тут второе окно блокируется (пробовал в хроме)
2) можно создать страницу, которая будет открывать новое окно (1), например: newwin.html (скорее всего оно тоже заблокируется, если только не заставить пользователя кликнуть по нему). кликаем по кнопке - срабатывает window.open('newwin.html', '_blank');
А на странице newwin.html: делаем кнопку, по клику на которую откроется новое окно (1) и окно (1) перейдет по другому адресу: window.location.href=...;